# How to locate the element in this?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium programming and have an issue.

```
z=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[3]/input[1]")
text = input("Gebietsdefinition: ")
z[0].send_keys(text)
time.sleep(2)
```

xpath : `/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/span`

id : `dijit_form_Button_18`

class : `dijit dijitReset dijitInline SendRequest dijitButton`

this is the full xpath, class & id of the button. But when I use the command,

`driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_form_Button_18").click()`

it executes in python without any error, but the webdriver stays the same.

**NB:** The button changes its class when I move the cursor over the button to "Hover" and changes to "Button ActiveFocused" when I click.

I hope somebody can shed some light into this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are tying to say that no error comes and click effect is also not visible.
Most probably, Selenium is clicking the element before it is clickable that is before the element is enabled to be clicked.
You can:

1. Introduce some delay in between using wait
2. Or you can use webdriverwait class and that will help

Comment: Thanks for your input @Rahul. But I have already tried it and still no effect on the button. But the code runs further without any error message.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the `HTML` with you, I hope that I can answer your population question. For the population question, you should import the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

and then you can try to populate your textbox with the following steps

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Your xpath here")
customText = "Your text here"
element.send_keys(customText)

# Gets the text that displays inside of our textbox after population
inputText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Your xpath here").get_attribute('value')
if inputText.lower() != customText.lower():
    raise Exception("Textbox failed to populate")
```

If the `input` tag is a button and has the following `class` elements

```
dijit dijitReset dijitInline SendRequest dijitButton
```

then you can use the following `xpath` to get your button

```
//input[contains(@class, 'SendRequest') and contains(@class, 'dijitButton')]
```

and then click it by using the following command

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class, 'SendRequest') and contains(@class, 'dijitButton')]").click()
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.